# python subprocess doesn't seem to work properly when there's no console attached

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, discord.py

I've been trying to make my own discord bot aimed at arbitrary code execution, and I'm quite happy with the result. However, it seems like whenever the bot is launched from anywhere without a console attached to it (ie. Systemd units, cron...) the behavior is unexpected and it's unable to get inputs or outputs properly. However, if it's launched from ssh or from the computer itself, none of this happens.

After some trial and error, I've ended up assuming that this must be caused by how subprocess handles stdout and stderr, but I'm not sure what's happening. This is the part of the code that handles subprocess generation.

```
def_subprocess(path_to_executable)

    timeout_flag = True
    run_process = subprocess.Popen(path_to_executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        stdout, stderr = run_process.communicate(timeout=5)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        stdout, stderr, timeout_flag = timeout(run_process)

    return stdout.decode("utf-8"), stderr.decode("utf-8"), timeout_flag




def timeout(process):
    line_number = 0
    stderr = b""
    stdout = b""
    while line_number < 5:
        stdout += process.stdout.readline()
        line_number += 1
    process.kill()
    timeout_flag = True
    return stdout, stderr, timeout_flag
```

It doesn't seem like there's no stdout or stderr, instead it feels like it doesn't wait for the process to finish and it just outputs garbage (Giving the bot the same input doesn't guarantee the same output, as you can see in this images:)

[image: as you can see in this image.]

[image: and in this other one too]

I'm baffled at this, and I don't have any idea about what could be happening.

Comment: `discord.py` is built on `asyncio`, is your code blocking when it shouldn't?  Are you getting errors/output in the console where you started the bot?  Any python errors that the bot produces will be outputted there.

Comment: That is the problem Patrick, when it's launched from a console none of that behavior happens. Instead, I get the expected behavior where everything works properly. It doesn't work when it doesn't have a console attached, and when that happens I can't check the output.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention you @PatrickHaugh.

Comment: That's odd.  What kind of values are you using for `path_to_executable`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh [here's the source code](https://github.com/Kurolox/ArcoexBot/blob/master/arcorun.py). I apologize if it's bad, this is one of my first "decent" projects.

Comment: Add an `on_ready` event that puts your PATH variable somewhere you can see it (maybe `#general` of your test server).  `cron` starts with a PATH different from your PATH, so your executable might not be in it

Comment: Besides your question: Note that the call to `process.kill()` is redundant. The subprocess has already been killed and it's pipes been fully drained when `TimeoutExpired` occurs. Otherwise, you'd have a race condition in the timeout-path (which you don't).

Comment: @PatrickHaugh if you're talking about the cwd, it's / when launched by cron. If you're talking about sys.path, it seems like it's exactly the same one if I'm launching the bot manually than when it's cron the one that launches it.

Comment: `'/bot', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'`

Comment: What user is the process running with when executed by systemd? Did you check your SELinux logs?

Comment: It's running as the same user than when I do it manually. I've checked the logs, but there's nothing relevant.

Answer (score 0):

While not really a solution, I've found a decent workaround by using screen as an intermediary between systemd and my bot. Systemd launches screen at boot, and screen handles my bot without presenting any of the issues. I'll stick with this.